# How to centralize elements that use text-align left

Tags: html, css, centering, epub

Is there any way to center elements that use `text-align: left` and doesn't involve `display: inline-block`?

I'm creating an epub and when centering the paragraphs through `div` and `inline-block` it breaks the page layout (see links with example).

HTML

```
  <h2 class="numero_hino"><a href="indice.xhtml"></a></h2>

  <h3 class="titulo_hino sigil_not_in_toc"></h3>

  <div class="centralizar-div">
    <div class="estrofe-div">
      <p class="estrofe"></p>

      <p class="estrofe"></p>

      <p class="estrofe"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
div.centralizar-div {
    text-align: center;
}

div.estrofe-div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

How it should be:
[Book in continuous mode (scroll down)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBonf.jpg)

How it is:
[Book in single page mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaG3G.jpg)

If anyone can help me :D

Comment: Change your div.estrofe-div { to div.estrofe-div p{

Comment: Visually works, but cause the same problem on epub single page read mode. With this change, instead of the page break forcing the parent div to stay on a single page, now the page break tries to hold at least one complete <p> element on an page.  If it were possible to make the page break works at the word level of the paragraph instead of paragraph itself I think it would fix the problem.

Comment: Can you show a gif of this exact problem after applying my suggestion? and What epub software are you using to generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of people's comments, I was researching until I found a way to solve the problem through flex items.
Follow the code

```
div.centralizar-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change `.estrofe-div p { display: inline-block; text-align : center }`

Comment: Not applicable as `text-align : center` would solve the problem by itself.  The issue is that I need the paragraphs centered and aligned to the left.

Comment: If I add "p" to `.estrofe-div  {`, goes to the same situation of Jae's post on main comments

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below css

```
div.estrofe-div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it just created many columns instead of centering the paragraphs in a "vertical line"

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using inline-block on your divs as way to position your content, we keep it the same and add an extra css targeting only the

tags.

```
div.centralizar-div {
    text-align: center;
}

div.estrofe-div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

div.estrofe-div p {
    text-align: left;
}
```